# procedure using record type

Tags: plsql, record, procedure

I would like to create a procedure which returns a list of the first five records. I must use record type and table type. What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE procedure_example(v_table OUT v_rec) IS
  CURSOR cur1 IS
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT
        type_note,
        note
      FROM dd_note ORDER BY type_note)
    WHERE rownum < 5;

  TYPE v_rec IS RECORD ( v_type_note NUMBER(2)
                       , v_note VARCHAR(30));
  TYPE v_table IS TABLE OF v_rec INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  BEGIN

    OPEN cur1;

    LOOP
      FETCH cur1 INTO v_type_note, v_note;

      dbms_output.put_line(v_type_note || '. --- ' || v_note);

      EXIT WHEN cur1%NOTFOUND;
      --enter code here
    END LOOP;

    CLOSE cur1;
  END procedure_example;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  Please show what the code does in its current state.

Answer (score 0):

The place where you declared your types is wrong. You must declare the type "v_rec" and type "v_table" in the package where this procedure belongs, NOT inside this procedure. Here's an improved version of your code. First, declare these types in your package:

```
 TYPE v_rec IS RECORD(
    v_type_note number(2),
    v_note varchar(30));
 TYPE v_table is table of v_rec index by pls_integer;
```

Then here's your function:

```
  create or replace PROCEDURE procedure_example (out_table OUT v_table) IS
     BEGIN
        select type_note, note BULK COLLECT into out_table from (select type_note, note from dd_note order by type_note) where rownum < 5
     FOR i in 1..out_table.COUNT LOOP
     dbms_output.put_line(out_table(i).v_type_note || '. --- ' || out_table(i).v_note);
     end loop;
  END procedure_example;
```